# clear backstack / history navigationdrawer item selected

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, navigation-drawer

In the MainActivity I have the NavigationDrawer which looks like this:

```
private void displayView(int position) { 

    ListFragment listFragment = null;

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        listFragment = new AlbumFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        listFragment = new TrackFragment();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (listFragment != null) {

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, listFragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

Within my AlbumFragment I can switch to the TrackFragment by clicking on listitems.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {    
    // get album & artist of selected album
    String album = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.albumTitle)).getText().toString();
    String artist = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.albumArtist)).getText().toString();
    String[] albumFilter = {"albumFilter", album, artist};

    // Create new fragment and transaction
    Fragment newFragment = new TrackFragment(); 
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putStringArray("filter", albumFilter);
    newFragment.setArguments(args);     

    FragmentTransaction transaction = this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
    // and add the transaction to the back stack
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Now the following problem occurs: If I press the Backbutton everything is fine and I'm back in the AlbumFragment. But If I open the NavigationDrawer and select the Tracksfragment and then press the Backbutton I get back to the AlbumFragment and behind it is still my TrackFragment.

Further Explanation: When I select an Album in the AlbumFragment only the Tracks from this album are shown. If I select Tracks from the NavDrawer ALL tracks are displayed.

So basically all I want is, that the entire Backstack-History is cleaned as soon as I select an Item from the NavDrawer.
I already tried most of the solutions to similar problems found on here but unfortuneatley nothing worked for me so far.

Has anybody got a solution for this problem?

Comment: I thought it might be as easy as adding this line:    `fm.popBackStackImmediate();`
before committing the transaction in my MainActivity. I also checked the BackStackEntryCount after doing so and it's at 0 so it works. 
The problem is that I get a NullpointerException caused by the AlbumFragment. I have no idea why it is executed after I use popBackStack()

Answer (score 0):

Use of android.support.v4.content.IntentCompat like this:

```
Intent intent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(new ComponentName(DrawerActivity.this, Tracksfragment.class));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set following flags in the intent while starting another activity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Where am I supposed to put this? Inside my MainActivity??? I'm sorry can you explain this more detailed?

Comment: You can put the code whenever you are starting your new Activity.  You must be doing that through Intents, right?

If you want to change Back button behaviour in certain activity, you can override onBackPressed() of that activity:

        @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
            // Start Activity here
        }

Comment: Okay, but I basically I only have one Activity which manages all my Fragments. So there is no need for Intents I guess. 
I know about overriding the backButton but I am trying to avoid messing around with it since I don't really want to change the default behaviour of it. 
I am still hoping for an approach to clean the BackStack-History when I select an Item of the NavDrawer.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution?  For fragments back stack history you can do something like         

**FragmentManager.popBackStack(String name, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)**

        

If you want to remove fragments from the back stack irrespective of tag or ID, use **fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()** instead.
   Take a look at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/0qXCA9rW7EI

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, I just can't get it right. It looks like the one in the link you posted has the same problem. I also want to clean the Backstack without popping anything.
I can't imagine that there is no solution for this problem or is there any different approach to get around this problem? The navigation in the Facebook-App is basically very similar to what I want to achieve.